# django template tag - comparing two variables

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% if firstpass != secondpass %}
        errors.append('Passwords are not the same')
```

I am trying to make a page where users can change their personal information. This one in particular pertains to checking whether the password textbox (firstpass) and password re-entering textbox (secondpass) contain the same password. For some reason, I am getting a compiler error on the line with the != sign. Can anyone suggest why? : (

Comment: The syntax of the first line is correct and != is a valid syntax for comparison. Can you say what was the error?

Comment: It was a compiler error. Nothing renders.

Comment: Are both firstpass and secondpass strings?

Comment: They are both <input type="text">

Comment: use `{% ifnotequal firstpass secondpass %}`

Comment: I can't imagine in what language this snippet is supposed to be valid. The first part is a template tag, but the second part appears to be Python - it can't be Javascript, as JS arrays don't have an `append` method (they have `push` instead). But Python of course isn't used in templates. Unless it's just plain text for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

If my taught is right you need to append this error message to `errors` list. Then you need to change it a bit.

First you need to create a form in template. I just create a dummy form for understand what happening.

```
<form action="/password-confirm/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="firstpass">
  <input type="text" name="secondpass">
  <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Second Create a view in `views.py`.

```
def password_confirm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        firstpass = request.POST["firstpass"]
        secondpass = request.POST["secondpass"]
        if firstpass == secondpass:
            // Write code if passwords are same.
        else:
            errors.append("Passwords are not the same")
    return render(request, 'password_confirm.html')
```

Third in `urls.py`.

```
url(r'^password-confirm/$', 'happytenants.views.password_confirm', name='about_us'),
```

And if you need to display error in template, you just pass the variable to template.

```
def password_confirm(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'password_confirm.html', {"errors": errors})
```